# How should percentual margin work on flex items?

Tags: css, flexbox

Trying to add a percentual `margin-top` to an item inside a flex container i noticed an inconsistency between Firefox and Chrome.

If the flex item declares `margin-top: 25%`, Firefox interprets that as putting it at a 25% of the parent's height (25 pixels in this case):

[image: Firefox rendering]

If the width of the parent element is changed, the child element doesn't move vertically, which i find quite intuitive.

But when i tried the same in Chrome, i found that the margin top is taken as a 25% of the parent *width* (50 pixels in this case):

[image: Chrome rendering]

If the width of the parent element is changed the child element moves up or down, which i find it really weird for an element that declares to be 25% from the top.

[Complete code on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y66h3zx3/2/).

Now, what is the correct behavior? Which browser is screwing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [**spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#item-margins)

> Percentage margins and paddings on flex items are always resolved against their respective dimensions; unlike blocks, they do not always resolve against the inline dimension of their containing block.
>
> **Note: This behavior is currently disputed, and might change in a future version of this specification to match the behavior of blocks.**

---

> Which browser is screwing up?

As you can see...both and neither. :)

Comment: Greaaaaat, so Firefox is doing it according to the spec, but Chrome wants to change it to a less intuitive behavior (for the sake of consistency with an old quirky behavior), so it implements flexbox differently, and given Chrome's market share dominance, it'll probably end up causing the spec to change :(

Comment: You'd be surprised. The Working Group can be a more sensible group than you might think.